# Can not record using Katalon studio with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: katalon-studio, ubuntu-20.04

I try to using Katalon studio on Ubuntu 20.04  to record for web testing purposes. But I have some errors and can not find any solution, here is pictures when I record with Firefox and Chrome

Error on Chrome

> /Chrome/Record/KR for Chrome not found

[image: Error on Chrome]

---

Error on Firefox

> Some empty error popup as snapshot

[image: Error on Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

This is my mistake, the reason is I'm not giving Katalon studio read/write permission